# oracle sql and plsql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table I am going to insert 1000 records and I just using insert using cursor. I have a error while inserting 901 record, will it stores upto 900 record?
what will happen remaining data's.

Comment: What's the error? All databases will easily store millions of rows. Big ones (Oracle between them) can easily go into the billions of rows.

Answer (score 1):

It won't store anything (at least, not the way you put it). Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test (id number(1));

Table created.

SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 1000 loop
  3      insert into test(id) values (i);
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
ORA-06512: at line 3


SQL> select * from test;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

But, if you `COMMIT` inside the loop (which is usually a **bad** idea), rows up to the erroring one will be stored into the table:

```
SQL> begin
  2    for i in 1 .. 1000 loop
  3      insert into test(id) values (i);
  4      commit;
  5    end loop;
  6  end;
  7  /
begin
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
ORA-06512: at line 3


SQL> select * from test;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
         6
         7
         8
         9

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: how to handle an exception within the loop so that it continues with execution]**

As I've said in the comment, you'd have to handle the error. Something like this:

```
begin
  for cur_e in (select empno, ename from emp) loop
    -- inner BEGIN begins here
    begin
      insert into some_table (col1, col2) values (cur_r.empno, cur_r.ename);
    exception
      -- if something happens, handle it. I'm using WHEN OTHERS, just as an example
      when others then 
        null;   -- don't do anything; silently skip it
    end;  -- end of the inner block
  end loop;
end;
```

Using such a code, you'll manage to insert all rows that do not fail. So, if it fails on 900th row, it'll just skip it and move on to 901st, 902nd, ... And if it fails on 950th, it'll skip it and move on to 951st etc.

Comment: not like that brother. i gave commiti in program.what i am asking is how many data's cursor will store while error in 901 record.whether it is store till 900 record or 900 and 902 to 1000 or nothing to be stored?

Comment: No? Why not? What's the difference? I showed you what happens when your code fails within the loop, which is what you asked. Doesn't matter that you use a cursor, and I do not - Oracle will behave just the same.

Comment: Aha; you added some more words to the comment. If you committed every insert, it'll store everything up to the error. As soon as the error happens, nothing will be stored (i.e. not 902nd record nor 903rd nor ... 1000th) **unless** you handle that exception within the loop.

Comment: I added another example into my answer; have a look

Comment: bro can you post same example using cursor

Comment: But, this **is** a cursor FOR loop, don't you see it?